# Hp dv6z(AMD version 3243cl) over heat & Battery Drain

Tags: 12.04, battery, overheating

I am new here on  Ubuntu(12.04 x64)!
The problem I am facing here is very less battery life and constant noise of fan during use of my laptop!
Laptop has AMD Phoneme II processor,6 gb ram ,Amd radeon mobility hd 4250 graphics..
I am not facing any issues regarding battery life or overheat on Windows 7(64 bit)!
I appreciate reading my problem and hoping to get a noob friendly reply !
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i was also having the almost same probem with amd with ubuntu 13.04  i installed the gnome shell extension "Radeon Power Profile Manager " which has the option to put the profile in low mode which a bit reduces the temp , but that's for gnome shell only with open source drivers

link to the extension : https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/356/radeon-power-profile-manager/